# Android MYSQL, PHP IMAGE upload to server issue

Tags: php, android, mysql, image, upload

I am developing an Android program and am using MYSQL and PHP to upload images and text to the server. It was not a problem when I added only text, but I added Asynctask twice while adding images, and found that the code did not work. Code at the point where the problem is expected, what's wrong with my code?

### Code

```
public void StudentRegistration(final String S_Name, final String S_Phone, final String S_Class) {

        class StudentRegistrationClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Loading Data",null,true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {
                super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,httpResponseMsg.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                hashMap.put("StudentName",params[0]);
                hashMap.put("StudentPhone",params[1]);
                hashMap.put("StudentClass",params[2]);
                finalResult = httpParse.postRequest(hashMap, HttpURL);
                return finalResult;
            }
        }

        StudentRegistrationClass studentRegistrationClass = new StudentRegistrationClass();
        studentRegistrationClass.execute(S_Name,S_Phone,S_Class);

    }
    private void showFileChooser () {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }

    private void uploadImage() {
        class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Bitmap,Void,String>{

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Uploading...", null,true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
                Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
                String uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmap);
                HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put(UPLOAD_KEY, uploadImage);
                finalResult = httpParse.postRequest(hashMap, HttpURL);
                return finalResult;
            }
        }

        UploadImage ui = new UploadImage();
        ui.execute(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Comment: where you call this uploadImage()?..try to make it one calss that send both it text and image

Comment: I advise you to come to my post. At the bottom of my post, I wrote how I resolved the problem [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48962016/my-path-file-return-to-me-null